# The parameterized query expects the parameter, which was not supplied

Tags: c#

I'm trying deserilize XML and insert it into a database.

Here is my code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //try
            //{

            List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE> deserializedList = new List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>();
            deserializedList = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>();


            var myPersons = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>()
                .Select(x => new Person
                {
                    PersonalIdentityNumber = x.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr,
                    LastName = x.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn,
                    FirstName = x.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn,
                    NationalRegistrationCountyCode = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.LanKod,
                    NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.KommunKod,
                    NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress2 : null,
                    NationalRegistrationPostCode = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.PostNr : null,
                    CitizenshipCode = x.Personpost.Medborgarskap.MedborgarskapslandKod
                    // and so on
                });


           var PersonalIdentityNber = deserializedList.Select(item => 


            string connetionString = null;


            SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            XmlReader xmlFile;



            connetionString = "Data Source=tsrv2062;Initial Catalog=Bums;User ID=BumsUser;Password=2tusen7Bums";


            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("navetout.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);


            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
            {
                connection.Open();



                DateTime datum = DateTime.Now;

                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Seamen SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, NationalRegistrationCountyCode = @NationalRegistrationCountyCode, NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = @NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode,NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = @NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2,NationalRegistrationPostCode = @NationalRegistrationPostCode, CitizenshipCode = @CitizenshipCode, LastChangedDate = @LastChangedDate WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber", connection);

                foreach (Person p in myPersons)
                {

                    command1.Parameters.Clear();
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", p.PersonalIdentityNumber);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", p.FirstName);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", p.LastName);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCountyCode", p.NationalRegistrationCountyCode);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode", p.NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2", p.NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationPostCode", p.NationalRegistrationPostCode);
                    ////command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCity", postOrt);
                    ////command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthCountyCode", fodelselanKod);
                    ////command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthParish", fodelseforsamling);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipCode", p.CitizenshipCode);
                    //// command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipDate", medborgarskapsdatum);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedDate", datum);



                    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Console.WriteLine(p.PersonalIdentityNumber);


                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

            //}// Put a break-point here, then mouse-over PersonalIdentityNumber...  deserializedList contains everything if you need it
        //   catch (Exception)
        //    {

        //        throw;
        //    }
        //    Console.ReadKey();
        //}

   class Person {
       public string PersonalIdentityNumber { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationCountyCode { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationPostCode { get; set; }
       public string CitizenshipCode { get; set; }
}
```

When I try this, I get error:

> The parameterized query '(@PersonalIdentityNumber
>   nvarchar(12),@FirstName nvarchar(14),@L' expects the parameter
>   '@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2', which was not supplied.

I have no idea why I get this error. Does anyone know why I get this error and how to solve it?

Comment: Make sure the parameters you're passing are not null. Also as you're passing a text query to the `SqlCommand` object are you sure it is using the parameters inside the `foreach`?

Comment: If the parameter value is `null` you have to set it to `DBNull.Value`, or it won't get bound.  Also you don't need to clear the parameters in the loop - just add the parameters outside the loop and set their value inside the loop.

Comment: @DStanley Where should I set it to `DBNull.Value`? The parameter "can" be null sometimes, I just don't the program to crash when that happens. Instead, I want it to return null and move on with the rest.

Comment: @John.P You set it to `DBNull.Value` in `AddWithValue`, or whenever you ultimately set the parameter value.  Ususally it's done with a null-conditional operator (e.g. `p.NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 ?? DBNull.Value`)

Comment: I tried it but got: 
`Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'`

Comment: Solved it.. Thank you for your help